# Initiate parameter to class that extend from parent by - node.js - awilix modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, koa

I would like to initiate a parameter in the child class and use it in the base class  , 
**i want to type this.smth that initiate in child constructor without call to super() because I need to use some services only in the parent**

thec child classes are initiated by using DI of node.js  using awilix 
the parent class is only when do an import.
  like the following:

```
modulesArr.push(['src/classes/*.js', Lifetime.SINGLETON])
container.loadModules(
    modulesArr,
    {
        formatName: 'camelCase'
    }
)
```

base class :

```
export default class BaseClass {

    constructor({aservice, bservice}){
        this.aservice = aservice
    }

    async testFun(){
       return this.testvar
    }

}
```

Extended class

```
import BaseClass from './base/base.class'
export default class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.testVar = "smth"

    }

    async testFun(){
       return this.testvar
    }

}
```

but then I got an error because I don't send the aservice and bservice to the super(aservice,bservice)

Answer (score 2):

In OOP in general, when you extend a class that does not have a default constructor (ie a contructor without any arguments), and if you redefine a constructor, you MUST call a base constructor with the expected arguments:

```
import BaseClass from './base/base.class'
export default class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {

    constructor({aservice, bservice}){
        super({aservice, bservice})
        this.testVar = "smth"

    }

    async testFun(){
       return this.testvar
    }

}
```

or:

```
import BaseClass from './base/base.class'
export default class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {

    constructor(){
        super({aservice: <something>, bservice: <something>})
        this.testVar = "smth"

    }

    async testFun(){
       return this.testvar
    }

}
```

In vanilla javascript (and es6) there can be only one contructor and the same rule applies.

If you can't do that, in other words if you can't honor the contract of the base class, that is indication that extending this class is not what you want to do.

Look into [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) pattern instead (having an instance of BaseClass as a member of ExtendedClass and call it's methods)

If you're the author of BaseClass, you may want to extract some of its features to made them availables by [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). And inject the desired feature in both BaseClass and extendedClass.